# Large Image/File Upload in Java application

Tags: java, apache, web, file-upload, inputstream

I am trying to upload an image. If the image is small, it is uploaded easily. However, if I try to upload a high quality large wallpaper, it takes forever. It shows upload 89% and remains like that. I am using Apache commons api to upload the file, and using `Inputstream` to read. Here is my code sample:

```
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(request);
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
        InputStream stream = item.openStream();
        if (item.isFormField()) {
            LOGGER.debug("Got a form field: " + item.getFieldName());
        } else {
            LOGGER.debug("Got an uploaded file: " + item.getFieldName() + ", name = " + item.getName());
            byte[] buf = new byte[stream.available()];
            ServletOutputStream outputstream = response.getOutputStream();
            while ((stream.read(buf)) != -1) {
                outputstream.write(buf, 0, buf.length);
            }
            outputstream.close();
            stream.close();
        }
    }
```

Is there any way I can upload the image quicker using the above code? Is there any apis that take care of it? I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explicit the size of your big file and the max Heap size of your JVM? (-Xmx java option)

It could simply be that your JVM is not allowed to get enough memory to manage your image correctly.
So one basic solution could be to enhance the value of the heap size to something larger as your file size.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting an OOM because of the code in the else block where you are allocating a byte array with stream.available to specify the size. If you read the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) for InputStreams available method, the available method may also return the total number of bytes in the stream and hence it should not be used for allocating buffers. May be you should use a small fixed size buffer.